# How do I debug a segfault which only occurs during vignette building?

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

I have Rcpp-based C++ code with a memory access bug which is only revealed when compiling vignettes (both in classic R and devtools manners).

The crashing code runs fine on its own in vanilla R environment.

I've tried things like:

`R -d gdb --vanilla -e "devtools::build()"
R -d gdb --vanilla -e "devtools::check()"`

but after digging deep I find that both `devtools` and `R` start new processes to build the vignettes during either building or checking a package.

I therefore modified `/usr/lib/R` to always be invoked `-d gdb -ex run` but this wouldn't run because it messed up the complicated argument passing between each of the steps.

I've no idea how to proceed at this point as I can't even reproduce the error with a simple R command invoking the compiled code. Could this be an unexpected interaction of Rcpp or other packages which differs between the vignettes building and vanilla interactive environment?

Comment: Have you tried `valgrind`? Kevin Ushey authored an awesome [article](http://kevinushey.github.io/blog/2015/04/05/debugging-with-valgrind/) on this very topic.

Comment: Oh dear. I think R goes of with a special reduced `.libPaths()` for the vignettes to find what may not have been declared via Suggests etc.  So it could be anything: stale/mismatched libraries, who know.  I would try to minimize to narrow down -- or else, just `eval=FALSE`.

Comment: @JosephWood yes, `valgrind` is good. What is less obvious is how to sneak it into the compilation call _during vignette processing_.

Comment: Will look into .libPaths(), thanks. Same problem injecting valgrind into R sub-processes as with gdb, I'm afraid.